# How can I use WinEdt to ensure successful using psfrag?

Tags: eps, winedt, psfrag

The following website provides an example of using the `psfrag` package to replace strings in EPS images.

- https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/psfrag-example/tggxhgzwrzhn

However, with my setup of WinEdt 11.1 and MiKTeX, I encounter difficulties in proceeding. I attempted using `Latex+dvi2pdf`, but the resulting PDF seems to be an intermediate file. How should I configure the settings?
[image]

Indeed, I see: Remember to compile your project with `LaTeX + dvipdfm` via the Project Settings.

[image]

But I still cannot configure them correctly.

P.S.(codes)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\title{psfrag Example}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}

\begin{document}

Remember to compile your project with \LaTeX\ + dvipdfm via the Project Settings. Click on the Overleaf menu icon in the upper left, above the file list pane, and set `Compiler' to `LaTeX' to do this!

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example}
\caption{Original EPS image}

\vskip3em

\psfrag{p1}{$p_1$}
\psfrag{p2}{$p_2$}
\psfrag{p3}{$p_3$}
\psfrag{\\tex[B][B]\{Plot of \$\\sin(t)\$ and \$\\cos(t)\$\}}{Plot of $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$}
\psfrag{\\tex[t][t]\{\$t\$\}}{$t$}
\psfrag{\\tex[B][B]\{\$\\sin(t)\$, \$\\cos(t)\$\}}{$\sin(t)$, $\cos(t)$}
\psfrag{-1}{-1}
\psfrag{-0.2}{-0.2}
\psfrag{-0.4}{-0.4}
\psfrag{-0.6}{-0.6}
\psfrag{-0.8}{-0.8}
\psfrag{0}{0}
\psfrag{0.2}{0.2}
\psfrag{0.4}{0.4}
\psfrag{0.6}{0.6}
\psfrag{0.8}{0.8}
\psfrag{1}{1}
\psfrag{2}{2}
\psfrag{4}{4}
\psfrag{6}{6}
\psfrag{8}{8}
\psfrag{10}{10}
\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example}
\caption{The same EPS image with psfrag}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can't use dvipdfm if you want to use psfrag, please clarify your question

Comment: Well. My example is from that website. I saw that it mentions we need to set up `LaTeX + dvipdfm`.   Perhaps it is incorrect? Anyway, I hope to see the correct replacement in the image.

Comment: yes so I saw, the comment is wrong I think. It gives the correct overleaf instruction (select latex in their menu) but that uses latex+dvips+pstopdf, not latex+dvipdfm,

Comment: you need to run latex then dvips then pstopdf, but I can't tell you how to do that in winedt

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestions are helpful enough for me.

Comment: if you have something working you could post a self answer

Comment: Just a fly-by: Overleaf with the "LaTeX" compiler option is running `dvipdf`, the instruction in our LaTeXMk file is `$dvipdf = "dvipdf -dNOSAFER -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY %O %S %D";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given answer is based on David Carlisle's reply and specifically pertains to operations in WinEdt. We simply need to locate the appropriate buttons for latex+dvips+pstopdf. They can be found in the Tex toolbar.

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

3.

[image]

Then it gives us:
[image]

Comment: thanks glad it all worked:-)